# Does anyone know if it is possible to open a C++ file outside of an XCode project and still be able to run it?

Tags: xcode

When you open a .cpp file with XCode, you can edit it and everything, but the run button doesn't show. You can convert it to a workspace, but even then, the run button is greyed out, even if you create a new scheme (since you can't create new targets in a workspace). I have also tried File > New > Project, but it doesn't transfer the files that are already in the workspace into the project. Help!

Comment: A `.cpp` file can't be run without its header file, `.h`, and usually these files are inside of a project with a build configuration that tells the compiler how to build a binary. Try copying the header file to your new project and resolving the linking issues.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.